# Text doesn't appear in edittext in some phones

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an `EditText` and a **Send** `Button` in a layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/messageLinearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sendButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Send"
        android:textColor="@color/blue"
        android:background="@drawable/send_button"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:enabled="false"
        />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/messageEditText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLines="4"
        android:maxLength="500"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/sendButton"
        android:background="@drawable/edittext"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

The purpose is to type in the `EditText` and then press **Send** to send the message.

I tried this in 4 different phones:

In all of them the keyboard shows up to type. In 3 of them (Smasung Galaxy S3, Samsung Galaxy S4, and Lenovo A820) I can type and see the text entered to the `EditText` (and send successfully, but that's irrelevant now).
In the 4th phone (Meizu MX5), I can't see what I'm typing (the background is white and the text is black - so that's not the problem). It doesn't even get to my `onTextChanged` listener with this phone.

Why is this happening and how can I solve it?

Here's the listener:

```
messageEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        if (!s.toString().isEmpty() && !send.isEnabled()) {
            send.setEnabled(true);
            send.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue));
        } else if (s.toString().isEmpty() && send.isEnabled()) {
            send.setEnabled(false);
            send.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.gray));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }
});
```

**Edit:**

- Lenovo A820 is using android version 4.1.2
- Samsung Galaxy S3 is using android version 4.3
- Samsung Galaxy S4 is using android version 4.4.2
- Meizu MX5 is using android version 5.01

**Edit2:**

OK this is really strange. Please check out the video:

http://vid90.photobucket.com/albums/k274/alaa_137/sendmessage_zpsqzar2fda.mp4

In the first 2 seconds, I'm typing, and nothing appears.

Then I long press the backspace button, "deleting" all what i had written.

Then I click one of the messages above (these are received messages).

The keyboard goes down (good).

I click the keyboard, and it goes up (good).

I start typing again, and I see Chinese characters! Also, the **Send** button doesn't become blue, which means it doesn't recognize any text in the `EditText`.

[This only happens in the Meizu]

**Edit3:**

The problem is in `inputType textMultiLine`. If I write `android:inputType="textCapSentences"` instead, everything works fine. But I do want the `textMultiLine`. So what can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem solved.

Change `inputType` in **xml** to:

```
android:inputType="textCapSentences"
```

And add to code after assigning the `EditText` instance:

```
messageEditText.setSingleLine(false);
messageEditText.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_FLAG_NO_ENTER_ACTION);
```

I don't know why, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Your `EditText`'s width is set to `match_parent` and since it is placed to left of the button, it wont show on smaller screens. Just use a `LinearLayout` instead of `RelativeLayout` and give the orientation horizontal and give the `Button` and `EditText` each a `layout_weight` of 1.

Comment: The problem actually is on larger screens (Meizu MX5), and not that the `EditText` isn't showing, it's just the text being written on it (i think). Anyway, I'll try that and update. Thanks

Comment: Still not working. Same problem. Please see **Edit**

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem on some devices (especially Samsungs). Turns out I had set this style (for some reason that I don't remember) on the EditText:

```
<EditText        
    android:id="@+id/idNumberText"
    style="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.EditText"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    ...
/>
```

Removing the style fixed the problem - I can now see the input text on the view